# Does c++ std::string are binary compatible between different compilers and std libraries?

Tags: c++, string, std, abi

I think it's impossible or very dangerous to send pointer / reference to dynamic loaded library from another compiler or ever another languages like C#. And I want to find proofs, but C++ standard documentation is pretty huge.

I think null terminated string will work fine, but how about std::string, or maybe string_view?

Comment: C++ does not standardize ABI

Comment: Short answer: no, C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not standardize ABI.

In practice, different `std::string` implementations may employ small string optimization differently tuned (with different buffer size), or no small string optimization. They may also have different order of fields. Additionally, `std::allocator` that allocates `std:;string` by default from different implementations may use different arenas.

`std::string_view` is more likely to match, though there could be variations (two pointers or pointer and size). Debug versions may have some additional information.